# Card element shrinks height when text is too long

Tags: flutter, widget, word-wrap

I have a class in my project which is supposed to show a column of cards.  Unfortunately I encountered some unexpected behavior: if the subtitle text is too long and gets wrapped, the whole card shrinks in size.

```
const double OUTER_SPACING = 24.0;
const double LINE_SPACING = 16.0;

class TempTypeSelection extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Select Type'),
            ),
            body:
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(OUTER_SPACING),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

                    children: <Widget>[
                        createListTile(context, Icons.check_circle_outline, "Title", "helpertext"),
                        createListTile(context, Icons.check_circle_outline, "Title", "helpertext " * 5),
                        createListTile(context, Icons.check_circle_outline, "Title", "helpertext"),
                    ]
                ))

        )
    );
}

Widget createListTile(BuildContext context, IconData icon, String title, String helper) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: LINE_SPACING),
        child: InkWell(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(icon),
                    title: Text(title),
                    subtitle: Text(helper),
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
}
}
```

See here:

[image: Screenshot for above code]

Is this a bug, or is it intended and I don't understand the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the intended behavior. If we have a look at the [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) source, we can see that `isTwoLine` handles the behavior:

```
double get _defaultTileHeight {
  final bool hasSubtitle = subtitle != null;
  final bool isTwoLine = !isThreeLine && hasSubtitle;
  final bool isOneLine = !isThreeLine && !hasSubtitle;

  if (isOneLine)
    return isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0;
  if (isTwoLine)
    return isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0;
  return isDense ? 76.0 : 88.0;
}
```

Sadly, I cannot tell you (yet) what the motivation behind this behavior is. If I find out more information I'll update this answer.

Comment: The code you are referencing will return 72.0 for all three tiles in the example (verified via debugger). I found the culprit in _RenderListTile.performLayout and will file a bug on github.